# Mediawiki extension to make comments on revisions

Tags: php, plugins, mediawiki, wikipedia

At my university, lots of teachers are using private wikis for their subjects. The students are told to populate those wikis, and the teachers evaluate their contributions afterwards.

However, currently that evaluation is merely based on straight figures, namely number of bytes, words or articles written, not the quality of them. Thus, I've been told to create an extension for Mediawiki to be able to "make comments" about the different revisions of each article.

For instance, suppose someone edits an article, adding a new paragraph. What we need is a way of commenting that revision of the article.

I'm pretty sure there must already be something similar to what I'm looking for. For example, this [Semantic history](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSemanticHistory) extension looks interesting, but seems to need a lot of time to get the full potential out of it.

Anyways, all the help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could the revision-specific comment be posted to Talk:ARTICLE/REVISION_NUMBER ? Perhaps the UI could be tweaked to support that.

Alternatively, maybe update Extension:LiquidThreads to enable the commented to enter a revision number in addition to the "subject" when starting a new discussion.